# trying to stretch <li> elements on the entire width of the <ul>

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

[image]

What I'm trying to do is exactly like in the above image. I get it only right for the first row, but the cubes of the second row stay together on the left side.

Here is the CSS:

```css
#menu ul {
    width: 60%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: justify;
}

#menu li {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: If possible can you please show us the DOM, so that we can know where and how exactly the menu and li items structured

Comment: For positioning items in any alignment and standing, I strongly suggest using [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Comment: It's a div with a simple list(ul and li) with empty elements. @Hypermystic